# How to display data from different database table entities in one page in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Suppose I have a mysql database and I have 3 entities,

1. TV
2. Laptop
3. Accessories

Each entities contains specific information.
I want to print those data into a single ctp page.
How can I do it?
I do not want to use `foreign_key`.

Comment: please add some more information.

Comment: I want to display data from 3 mysql tables into a cakephp template (ctp) using a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cake's loadModel function to call in data from any table into your current controller. More info towards the bottom of this [page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html).

`$this->loadModel('YourModel');`

Then set the variable to make it available in your view:

```
$this->set('yourModel', $this->YourModel->find('all', $settings);
$this->loadModel('YourOtherModel');
$this->set('yourOtherModel', $this->YourOtherModel->findI('all', $settings);
```

Having now set two variables from your Model they are available to you in your view.

(Use debug to see all the data which is available i.e. `debug($yourModel);` You can put this in your controller action and it will output at the top of the page, or anywhere in your view file)

Comment: But I want to print all data in a single ctp file

Comment: @Rezaul You can print all the data in a single ctp file

We have loaded the data by calling it using the loadModel method
We have stored two variables and set them, this is now available for the view file

What else do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

if you display data in table the code might be similler like this:

```
<table>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Title</th>        

        <?php foreach ($array as $temp_variable):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $temp_variable['ModelName']['ColumnName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $temp_variable['ModelName']['ColumnName']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

for one array..similar thing do for rest of the arrays...
i hope you understand.

Comment: How would controller works? How controller would grab data from multiple database ? We always read data from database using $this->Tutorial->read(null,$id); this method but when I want to read from multiple database what should I do ?